# How to set up a dialog box that allows users to input data?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am doing a school project and i want to set it up so when the user presses a button a dialog box pops up and allows users to input data. How should I implement this? I use resedit if that matters.

Comment: You will have to mention the framework or api that you are using. Standard C++ has no concept of a GUI. Also you probably should include a minimal code example. [mcve]

Comment: What platform?  What GUI framework?  MFC has a different method for creating dialog boxes than wxWidgets and Qt.  Linux has a different system as well.

Comment: I use Win32 GUI.

Comment: If you don't know how to edit a dialog resource or create a modal dialog, then the next step is to read some tutorials at CodeProject.com, Microsoft, the Petzold book, etc. -- please read [tour] and [ask] to see what kind of questions are good for StackOverflow.  "Getting started" and tutorial questions are usually better answered by searching for blogs, tutorials, YouTube videos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple demo, you can refer to the following code

Compiler tool: VS2017

```
// WindowsProject29.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WindowsProject29.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define IDB_ONE 133

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
HWND hWnd;
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
ATOM                MyRegisterClass_1(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void DisplayModelDialog(HWND hParent);
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT29, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    MyRegisterClass_1(hInstance);
    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT29));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT29));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1));
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT29);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass_1(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = DialogProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT29));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1));
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT29);
    wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("Dialog");
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

 //  DisplayModelDialog(hWnd);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Click", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            35, 10, 120, 60, hWnd, (HMENU)IDB_ONE, hInst, NULL);
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case IDB_ONE:
                DisplayModelDialog(hWnd);

                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}


void DisplayModelDialog(HWND hParent) 
{
    EnableWindow(hParent, FALSE);

    HWND hDlg = CreateWindow(
        TEXT("Dialog"),
        TEXT("Dialog"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500,
        300,
        hParent,
        NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);
    HWND EDIT= CreateWindow(L"edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
        20, 20, 200, 50, hDlg, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hDlg);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    EnableWindow(hParent, TRUE);
    SetForegroundWindow(hParent);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (message) {

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Debug Result:
[image: Design sketch]

More details, such as the need to save the text of the edit box and so on, can be added according to the actual situation.